# ZF2 использование нескольких подключений к БД

Tags: zend-framework-2, php, база-данных

Как можно осущитсвить подключение к нескольким БД на примере ZF2 Skeleton Application? 
Есть ли вариант, что-бы в config/autoload/global.php добавить:

```
'db' => array(
        'db1' => array(
            'driver'    => 'Pdo',
            'dsn'       => 'odbc:db1',
            'username'  => 'user',
            'password'  => 'pass'
        ),
        'db1' => array(
            'driver'    => 'Pdo',
            'dsn'       => 'odbc:db2',
            'username'  => 'user',
            'password'  => 'pass'
        ),
    ),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'ZendDbAdapterAdapter'
                => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

а потом передавать в адаптер? Или как можно получить этот объявленный массив настроек в классе модели?

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:
 1. В config/autoload/global.php добавил объявление адаптеров для различных подключений к БД

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'ZendDbAdapterAdapterdb1' => function($sm) {
                 $config = $sm->get('Config');
                 return new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db1conf']);
             },
            'ZendDbAdapterAdapterdb2' => function($sm) {
                 $config = $sm->get('Config');
                 return new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db2conf']);
             },
        ),
    ),
```

2. В config/autoload/local.php добавил настройки для драйвера

   ```
   'db1conf' => array(
       'driver'    => 'Pdo',
       'dsn'       => 'odbc:db1odbc',
       'username'  => 'username',
       'password'  => 'password'
   ),
   'db2conf' => array(
       'driver'    => 'Pdo',
       'dsn'       => 'odbc:db2odbc',
       'username'  => 'username',
       'password'  => 'password'
   ),
   ```

А далее вызов адаптеров как в документации(быстрый старт).